# Bcdboot equivalent for Linux (Lubuntu and Ubuntu)

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, lubuntu

All my searches have turned up a bunch of boot loaders, grub, grub2, etc.  I have read about the boot repair iso.  However I like a manual way of doing it.

For example I can easily in Windows:

```
bcdboot c:\windows /s e: /f UEFI  # changing volume letters as needed
```

And booting is fixed.

There has to be a simple as this way to take a blank efi Ubuntu or Lubuntu partition and put the boot code on it.  Any help finding the command lines (terminal lines) to achieve this.  Thanks.

Comment: Your `bcdboot` command is run using details specific to the OS/release you're using (ie. "c:\windows" is a directory of the drive label C: currently in use), so don't forget your windows command is not *generic*. The commands current Ubuntu/Lubuntu uses that is closest is `grub-install` which is coded to use the GRUB version specific to your *unstated* ubuntu 2 release (it'll be a GRUB 2 version for your *unstated* release, ie. it'll be the appropriate version for used where the command is run) If you've replaced the default GRUB boot loader command will differ.

Comment: Lubuntu 22.04 on uefi.  Where do I run grub-install, from an install disk?  I am just trying to understand how to make a lubuntu installation boot up if I had the 300mb efi partition blank and the root partition is fine, has all the data, etc.  I am not interested in a "boot menu". I have seen the term efibootmgr in some post, what does it do.  Linux has to have an equal one liner similar to what bcdboot does in WIndows, thanks.

Comment: Grub exists in multiple stages. the first stage exists on the MBR or ESP (*uEFI System Partition*) and this is what `grub-install` writes.. It gets the rest of the details from the system that is running (*just like your `bcdboot` got details from the running windows*) where the later stages of grub (stages 1.5, 2 etc) exist in the `/boot/grub/` directory of the GNU/Linux partition (Ubuntu in this case). `update-grub` will deal with those, `grub-install` will write the MBR or ESP as required by the system that is running (*you specify drive, as each drive can by standard have its own MBR/ESP*)

Comment: Okay, if I currently have a blank 300mb fat32 efi partition with nothing on it from where do I run grub-install.  Assuming The system doesn't currently boot up. And what exactly would the terminal command look like? That's what I'm after.  And what is efibootmgr?

Comment: After finding and trying things from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing All I got is error after error. The efi partition was sda1 the main partition sda2, it wouldn't even mount. I tryed ```sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt``` then ```sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda``` But errors, because probably ```sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot``` wouldn't mount.  A not found in fstab I believe it said.  Folks there has got to be a way (workable easy way) to write boot code to sba1.  Anybody?